# python program for printing boundary elements of matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

My code :

```py
R = int(input("Enter the Size of Square Matrix : "))
matrix = []

print("\nEnter the entries row-wise : ")
for i in range(R):
    a = []
    for j in range(R):
        a.append(int(input()))
    matrix.append(a)

print("\nMatrix : \n")
for i in range(R):
    for j in range(R):
        print(matrix[i][j], end=" ")
    print()
print("\n")

print("\nBoundary Matrix\n")
for i in range(R):
    for j in range(R):
        if (i == 0):
            print(matrix[i][j])
        elif (i == R - 1):
            print(matrix[i][j])
        elif (j == 0):
            print(matrix[i][j])
        elif (j == R - 1):
            print(matrix[i][j])
        else:
            print(" "),
    print()
```

output :

```sh
Boundary
Matrix

1
2
3

4

6

7
8
9
```

I'm not able to print the boundary elements in form of a matrix. the output is in form of a straight line.

Please help me to do so.

Note: I have tried changing the position of print() but that didn't help much.

Comment: What is the expeted output ?

Answer (score 1):

```py
print("\nBoundary Matrix\n")
for i in range(R):
    print(
        "{}{}{}".format(
            "\t".join(map(str, matrix[i])) if i in (0, R - 1) else matrix[i][0],
            "" if i in (0, R - 1) else (" \t" * (R - 1)),
            "" if i in (0, R - 1) else matrix[i][R - 1],
        )
    )
```

```sh
Matrix : 

1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
9 10 11 12 
13 1 4 15 



Boundary Matrix

1   2   3   4
5           8
9           12
13  1   4   15
```